# The return value of >> operator

Tags: c++

I just read an [article](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/io-operators.html) that says:

> using the `>>` operator returns the operand which is on the left side of the `>>` operator.

Also, it gives some examples like:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    cout << "Insert 3 integers " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The three integers are " << endl << a << endl << b << endl << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Is the quoted sentence true? I can't find this information in my book, nor any other reference websites.

Comment: Try those references: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion and  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: The istream's operator >> returns a reference to the stream. But generally an overloaded operator >> can return anything.

Comment: @dedObed Minor nit-pick: OP asks about `>>` but you cite `<<`. :-P

Comment: Operators for fundamental types are defined by the language and must return the result of the requested arithmetic.  But user-defined types can overload operators to return anything they want.

Comment: "It then returns the left operand" and your quote has some potential for misunderstanding when considered in isolation. `a >> b` does in general not return the left operand. Thats just what the streams overloads do. In general `operator>>` can be overloaded to return any type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `>>` operator for input streams ([that is, classes derived from `std::basic_istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)) does, indeed return its left-hand operator. This is so that you can 'chain' input operations, as you have done in your `cin >> a >> b >> c;` statement.

Looking at what this does, we first input `a` from `cin` and then continue by inputting `b` from the *returned value* of that `cin >> a` operation. And, then again, for the third input (to `c`).

So, adding parentheses for clarity, we get:

```cpp
( ( ( cin >> a ) >> b ) >> c );
//               ^ Here, the LH operand is the returned value of (cin >> a)
```

If the `>>` operator did *not* behave this way, we would have to write that *single* statement as three separate ones, like this:

```cpp
cin >> a; cin >> b; cin >> c;
```

The `<<` operator (for output streams) works in a very similar way.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's true when used for `std::istream`s. This:

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

becomes this:

```
std::cin.operator>>(a).operator>>(b).operator>>(c);
```

That is, `cin >> a` returns an `std::istream&` (to `std::cin`) which is then used for `>> b` that returns an `std::istream&` which is used for `>> c`.

Comment: Note that it returns an `istream &` and only an `istream &`. If you're working with a `ifstream`, you'll get back an `istream &` and cannot use it as an `ifstream &` by, for example, invoking `is_open`.

Comment: "*This ... becomes this ...*" - not always. It could also be more like this instead: `operator>>(operator>>(operator>>(std::cin, a), b), c)`, or any combination of `lhs.operator>>(rhs)` and `operator>>(lhs, rhs)`. It really depends on the particular types of `a`, `b`, and `c`, and if/how their operators are overloaded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. This was for the types used in the question where `istream` has member overloads for `operator>>` but as you say, with other types, one can get different "unpacking" of what really goes on. https://cppinsights.io/ is good for experimenting with different types to see what actually goes on.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*This was for the types used in the question where `istream` has member overloads for `operator>>`*" - that is a good point, I didn't notice the types being used.